# Проверка на полиндром

Tags: java

Решаю задачи по java. Дошел до интересной задачи про полиндромы.
Суть такая - введите число и проверть его на полиндромность. Я не понимаю как это мне сделать?! Помогите.

```
public static boolean iSPolindrome (int number) {
    if (number <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int left = 0;
    int rigth = 0;

    while (number > 0) {
        rigth = number % 10;
        left = 10 * left + rigth;   
        if (rigth == left) {
            return true;             
        }
        number /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: как вариант - переведите число в строку и проверьте строку.

Comment: Проще всего будет перевести число в строку. И проверять символ слева с символом справа если они равны то идти к центру числа, иначе вернуть отрицательный результат. (`false`) Если дошли до центра, то вернуть положительный результат (`true`)

Comment: по условиям задачи я не должен испольовать строки и массивы. Токо с потощью / и % разбивать число. Причем это делать я умею. только не понимаю как мне в чикле записать сравнение левой и правой цифры. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Помогите мне.

Comment: ну а Stack, Queue или LinkedList вам можно использовать?

Comment: Нет. Нужно использовать только / и %.

Comment: Правильно говорить "п**а**линдром".

Comment: Если `right == left` еще не факт, что число палиндром, зато если `right != left` число точно не является палиндромом.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, вы можете перевернуть число и сравнить оригинал с перевертышем

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(123));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(321));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(121));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(212));
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    int revert = revertNUmber(number);
    return revert == number;
}

public static int revertNUmber(int number) {
    int ret = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        ret += number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        if (number > 0) ret *= 10;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Вывод

```
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: Только проблемка может появится если перевернутое число будет > максимального значения `int`. Может лучше тогда использовать `long`?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков от задачи зависит, ведь у long тоже есть пределы. Но я не думаю, то это тут имеет значение, цель моего ответа показать принцип, а не удовлетворять всем граничным условиям.

Comment: Ну раз вы показываете принцип работы используя `int`, то можно показать и возможную проблему, а так же способ решения проблемы. Разве нет? Чтобы автор попробовав вести такое число не задался вопросом: "а почему так?".

Comment: ок, я вам даю эксклюзивное право написать дополнение к моему ответу, раз вам это так важно. Сформулируйте как хотите, будем считать, что  я вам полностью доверяю :)

Comment: Хотя я подумал и не такого числа  типа `int`, чтобы перевернутое число, даже если будет переполнение, не будет положительным, что уж там говорить о возможном палиндроме. В общем все нормально :)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков круть! Это тоже полезно знать, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

В комментариях уже всё объяснили, ну а в том, что касается кода... Разбейте строку на массив символов. И в цикле проверяйте:

```
for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length / 2; i++) {
    if (symbols[i] != symbols[symbols.length - 1 - i]) {
        System.out.println("Число - не палиндром!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Без массивов решение следующее: в цикле сравнивайте цифру с правой части числа и с левой. Для того чтобы получить по одной циферке с каждой стороны, делаем так:

- Для левой стороны: `num / pow(10, degree - i - 1) % pow(10, i)`
- Для правой стороны: `num % pow(10, degree - i - 1) / pow(10, i)`

`num` - это само число
`i` - это переменная цикла.
`degree` - это, собственно, сколько цифр в числе.
`pow()` - метод возведения в степень. Эту операцию надо проводить в цикле.

Comment: `по условиям задачи я не должен испольовать строки и массивы.`

Comment: @tym32167 а как я должен был догадаться? // Прошу прощения, я думал вы - ТС.

Comment: @Zhenyria я написал в условии это

Comment: @Drseal90 неправда. Вы написали это в комментариях. Вопрос должен быть полностью изложен в вопросе, чтобы отвечающий не выискивал кусочки вопроса в комментариях.

Comment: да, я тоже попался и предложил поначачу использовать строку

Comment: @Zhenyria Буду знать. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я дико извиняюсь за то, что код привожу на C++, а не Java. Полагаю, что главное тут - алгоритм, и переписать его на Java не составит особого труда, тем более что эти два языка очень похожи.
Не содержит строки и массивы, что по условию вашей задачи должно подходить:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

int main()
{
    uint num,left,right;

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%u", &num);

    uint order = 0;
    if (num) order = floor(log10(num));
    uint denum = round(pow(10.0,order));

    bool bPalindrome = true;
    left = right = num;
    order = (order+1)>>1;

    for (uint i=0; i<order; ++i)
    {
        uint left_digit = left/denum;
        uint right_digit = right%10;
        if (left_digit!=right_digit)
        {
            bPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }

        left%= denum;
        denum/= 10;
        right/= 10;
    }

    if (bPalindrome) printf("The number %u is palindrome\n",num);
    else printf("The number %u is NOT palindrome\n",num);

    return 0;
}
```